# Error: Laravel Notifications Broadcast Exception

Tags: notifications, laravel-5.4, pusher

I am trying to build a real-time notification system in an app I am working on. one of the requirements is, when an ID is expired, that particular user should be sent a notification. Since this task needs to be run on daily basis at the maximum, I developed an artisan command that is easy to run with CRON jobs i.e. Laravel Scheduler. Every thing is working fine i.e. the artisan command is run and notification is generated & stored in database & all the related stuff. but each time a notification is generated, the page needs to be reload and this is where I am stuck. I am trying to make it happen in real time but a very strange error is being thrown & I don't know what it means.

Here is the necessary code:

### Artisan.file

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Notifications\UserIdExpired;

class UpdateCatalog extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'check:expiry';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'dummy command to check its purpose';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $ZERO = 0;
        $MONTH = 30;
        $today = Carbon::today();
        $users = User::all();
        foreach($users as $user){
            $today = Carbon::today();
            $expiryDate = $user->qidexpire_on;

            if($today->diffInDays($expiryDate, false) <= $MONTH && $today->diffInDays($expiryDate, false) >= $ZERO){
               $this->info($user);
                $this->info($expiryDate->diffInDays($today));
                $user->notify(new UserIdExpired);

            } else {


            } 
            }

        }
    }
}
```

### Notification.file

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Carbon\Carbon;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;


class UserIdExpired extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;


    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database', 'broadcast'];
    }

    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'user' => $notifiable,
            'id_expired' => Carbon::now()
        ];
    }

    public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
    {
        return new BroadcastMessage([
            'user' => $notifiable,
            'id_expired' => Carbon::now()
        ]);
    }


}
```

when I run `php artisan check:expiry` from console, Notification is generated & on page reload it updates number of notifications but its not happening in real time. Following is the error that is shown on console

```
[Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException]
```

Note: Whenever i reload the page, Pusher Console shows the respective log like connected private channel and host & all that stuff which means the problem is not on the client side, (yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just found the answer on this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16478)

had to encrypt `false` since I am developing locally

Comment: Hi Lahori, normally `encrypted: true` works fine when developing locally. Were you using something like Fiddler?

Comment: I don't understand what you are referring to but I am using https://laragon.org/ for development.